# Converting resource to string list with Terraform interpolation

Tags: interpolation, terraform

Given a `.tfvars` containing:

```
environment = "dev"
web_servers = ["192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2"]
```

and a `node` resource like:

```
resource "node" "web_nodes" {
  count = "${length(var.web_servers)}"
  name = "${var.environment}_web_${count.index}"
  address = "${element(var.web_servers, count.index)}"
}
```

I want to express the following dynamically:

```
resource "pool" "homepage_pool" {
  name = "homepage_${var.environment}"
  nodes = [
    "dev_web_0:443",
    "dev_web_1:443"
  ]
}
```

with a plan output like:

```
nodes.2387117855: "" => "dev_web_1:443"
nodes.3005787823: "" => "dev_web_0:443"
```

I think that `pool.nodes` should be generated using something like `formatlist()` or `join()` or a combination of the 2. Struggling to find decent examples.

The closest I can get results in a plan like:

```
nodes.467461356: "" => "\"/Common/preprod_web_0\","/Common/preprod_web_1\""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `formatlist` function can be used in conjunction with the "splat" operator to get the result you need here.

The "splat" operator allows you to concisely create a list from a given attribute of a set of `count`ed resource instances. Your example here it seems that you want to use the node name and a hard-coded port 443, in which case this can be expressed as follows:

```
resource "pool" "homepage_pool" {
  name = "homepage_${var.environment}"
  nodes = "${formatlist("%s:443", node.web_nodes.*.name)}"
}
```

The notation `node.web_nodes.*.name` means to take the `name` attribute of each of the instances created under the name `node.web_nodes` and produce a list of strings from them. `formatlist` then applies the given format to each element of the list in turn, appending the `:443` port suffix.

Comment: Nodes only takes a list. So I simply had to add the `[]` like `nodes = ["${formatlist("%s:443", node.web_nodes.*.name)}"]`. Thanks very much, one of those where I could have sworn I'd tried that!

Comment: Great! The extra wrapping brackets shouldn't be needed on recent versions of Terraform, but were needed on some older versions. (I think it was changed in one of the 0.9 releases, IIRC.)